# Как отсортировать vector по значениям в map

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector, map

У меня есть вектор

```
std::vector <std::string> v; // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

и отображение, в котором ключи - элементы вектора, а значение - просто целое число

```
std::map <std::string, int> m; // {"a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=1}
```

Как мне отсортировать элементы вектора по числовым значениям в `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),
     [&m](const string& a, const string& b){return m[a] < m[b]; });
```

Примерно так... Ну, или если `m` - глобальная, то без `&m` в квадратных скобках.